# The completion of $F/\text{Ker}(M)$ is isomorphic to the closure of the range of $M$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $M$ be a **positive semidefinite** operator on a complex Hilbert space $(F,(\cdot,\cdot))$.

On the quotient space $F/\text{Ker}(M)$ we have the following inner product
$$\langle \overline{x},\overline{y}\rangle = (Mx,y),$$
for all $\overline{x},\overline{y}\in F/\text{Ker}(M)$.

According to some papers, the following theorem figures in [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000VJD14C).  However, I don't find it and I hope to get its proof.

> **Theorem:** The completion of $F/\text{Ker}(M)$ denoted $\overline{F/\text{Ker}(M)}$ is isometrically isomorphic to the Hilbert space $\text{Im}(M^{1/2})$
>   with the inner product
>   $$( M^{1/2}x,M^{1/2}y)_0=(P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}x, P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}y),\;\forall\, x,y \in F.$$
>   $P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\overline{\text{Im}(M)}$.

I think that in order to prove the theorem it suffices to show that

> The completion of $F/\text{Ker}(M)$ is isomorphic to $(\overline{\text{Im}(M)}, (\cdot,\cdot)_0)$. Is this claim true?

Comment: Why do you expect this to be true?

Comment: Oh, actually these are two Hilbert spaces, so the whole point is to check that they have the same dimension...

Comment: @YCor But we work in infinite dimensionel Hilbert spaces

Comment: Yes, a Hilbert space is determined up to linear isometry by its dimension  (in the Hilbert sense: cardinal of an orthogonal basis). This is one of the very first things to know about a Hilbert space.

Comment: Completion of $F/\operatorname{Ker}(M)$ with respect to the $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_M$ norm?

Comment: Also, it is implicitly assumed that $M$ is selfadjoint, no? (Since $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle_M$ is supposed to be a (semi-) inner product.)

Comment: Yes M is selfadjoint since it is positive.

Comment: @Hannes: Just to add a few details to Schüler's answer to your comment: A bounded linear operator $A$ on a complex Hilbert space is self-adjoint if and only if $\langle Ax, x\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for all vectors $x$; this follows from the polarisation identity.

Comment: Probably I am missing something essential, but why is the norm induced by the inner product $(x,y) \mapsto \langle Px, Py \rangle$ on $\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})$ complete?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Please see my edit.

Comment: Considering your first question, I now have severe doubts that this is true. Let $H =\ell^2$, let $M$ be the multiplication with the sequence $(1/n)$. Then $P$ is the identity, but the image of $M^{1/2}$ is a dense and proper subspace of $\ell^2$, and thus, it is not complete with respect to the standard scalar product on $\ell^2$, right?

Comment: @Schüler: Alright, I see. I missunderstood the definition of the scalar product on the range of $A^{1/2}$. What the authors actually do is to define a scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{R(A^{1/2})}$ on $R(A^{1/2})$ by means of the formula $(x,y)_{R(A^{1/2})} = (PA^{-1/2}x, PA^{-1/2}y)$ for all $x,y \in R(A^{1/2})$. This resolves my concerns; I simply missinterpreted the notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is going on is the following.

As Meisam Soleimani Malekan says, for any Hilbert space $H$ with inner product $(\cdot|\cdot)$, and $\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}T\in\mc B(H)$, we have that $\ker T^*T=\ker T$, because $T^*T\xi=0\implies (T^*T\xi|\xi)=0 \implies \|T\xi\|^2=0\implies T\xi=0$.  Also, $\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}(\im T)^\perp = \ker T^*$ by an easy calculation.

For your $F$ and $M\in\mc B(F)$ positive we hence have that $\ker M = \ker M^{1/2}$ and so on $F / \ker M$ we may define an inner product
$$ \newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle{#1},{#2}\rangle} \ip{\overline{x}}{\overline{y}} = (Mx|y) = (M^{1/2}x|M^{1/2}y). $$
Here $\overline{x} = x+\ker M = x+\ker M^{1/2}$ is the equivalence class of $x\in F$.  It is evident that $\overline{x} = \overline{x'} \implies x-x'\in\ker M^{1/2} \implies M^{1/2}x = M^{1/2}x'$, so the definition is well-defined.  Notice that we have not established that $F/\ker M$ is complete for this inner-product.

---

Alternatively, in any Hilbert space $H$, if $X\subseteq H$ is a closed subspace, then we can identify $H/X$ with $X^\perp$.  Indeed, let $P:H\rightarrow X^\perp$ be the orthogonal projection, and define $\theta:H/X\rightarrow X^\perp; \overline{\xi}\mapsto P(\xi)$.  This is well-defined, for $\overline{\xi}=\overline{\eta}\implies \xi-\eta\in X \implies P(\xi-\eta)=0$, and similarly $\theta$ is injective, as $P(\xi)=0$ exactly when $\xi\in X$.  By construction $\theta$ is onto, and so $\theta$ is an isomorphism.

**However** this construction, applied to your setting, identifies $F/\ker M$ with $(\ker M)^\perp = (\im M)^{\perp\perp} = \overline{\im M}$ which is already a Hilbert space, so complete.  The inner product we get on $F/\ker M$ is $(\overline x|\overline y) = (P(x)|P(y))$.  Suppose we choose $x$ and $y$ already in $\overline{\im M}$. Then $(\overline x|\overline y) = (P(x)|P(y)) = (x|y)$.  This **is not** the inner product you want.

---

**Instead** let's define $U:\im(M^{1/2})\rightarrow F/\ker M$ as follows.  Define $U(\xi) = \overline{x}$ if $\xi = M^{1/2}x$ for some $x\in F$.  This is well-defined, for if also $\xi=M^{1/2}y$ then $x-y\in\ker M^{1/2}=\ker M$ so $\overline{x}=\overline{y}$.  Furthermore, for $\xi=M^{1/2}x$ and $\eta=M^{1/2}y$,
$$ \ip{U(\xi)}{U(\eta)} = \ip{\overline x}{\overline y} = (Mx|y)
= (M^{1/2}x|M^{1/2}y) = (\xi|\eta). $$
Hence $U$ is an isometry.  Clearly $U$ is surjective.  So
$$ U^{-1} : \big( F/\ker M, \ip{\cdot}{\cdot} \big) \rightarrow
\big( \im(M^{1/2}), (\cdot|\cdot) \big) $$
is an isometric linear isomorphism.  This identifies $F/\ker M$, given the inner-product you have defined, with the (in general not closed) subspace $\im(M^{1/2})$ of $F$.  In particular, $F/\ker M$ might fail to be a Hilbert space.

However, if we take the *completion* of $F/\ker M$ then $U^{-1}$ extends to a unitary showing that $\overline{F/\ker M}$ is isomorphic to $\overline{\im(M^{1/2})} = \overline{\im(M)}$, the latter viewed as a subspace of $F$.

---

Your theorem  suggests that we give $\im(M^{1/2})$ a *different* inner-product,
$$ (M^{1/2}x|M^{1/2}y)_0 = (Px|Py) $$
where I have written $(\cdot|\cdot)_0$ to avoid confusion with $(\cdot|\cdot)$ which is the given inner-product on $F$.  Define a *different* map $V:F/\ker M \rightarrow \im M^{1/2}$ by
$$ V(\overline x) = Mx = M^{1/2} M^{1/2} x \in \im M^{1/2}. $$
Again, this is well-defined.  As $\overline{\im M} = (\ker M)^\perp = (\ker M^{1/2})^\perp = \overline{\im M^{1/2}}$, we have that $PM^{1/2}x=M^{1/2}x$, and so
$$ (Mx|My)_0 = (M^{1/2} M^{1/2} x|M^{1/2} M^{1/2} y)_0 = (PM^{1/2}x|PM^{1/2}y)
= (M^{1/2}x|M^{1/2}y) = \ip{\overline x}{\overline y}. $$
Thus
$$ V:\big( F/\ker M, \ip{\cdot}{\cdot} \big) \rightarrow \big( \im M^{1/2}, (\cdot|\cdot)_0 \big) $$
is an isometry, as you want.  Notice that $V$ is not (in general) onto.  Finally, we can extend $V$ to the completion of $F/\ker M$, and then we will obtain a unitary transformation onto $\overline{\im M^{1/2}}$, completion with respect to $(\cdot|\cdot)_0$.

Comment: I don't fully understand.  Firstly, $\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})$ is not closed, so it is not a Hilbert space.  Secondly, in what sense does $M^{1/2}$ map between $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(M)}$ and $\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})$?  Do you closure here?  But then $\overline{\operatorname{Im}(M)} = \overline{\operatorname{Im}(M^{1/2})}$ so $M^{1/2}$ does not map between them bijectively.  Thirdly, you keep writing $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ but this is used in lots of different ways in your question, so I don't really know what inner product is meant.

Comment: $\text{Im}(M^{1/2})$ is a Hilbert space 
with respect to the following inner product
$$( M^{1/2}x,M^{1/2}y)=\langle P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}x, P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}y\rangle,\;\forall\, x,y \in F.$$
$P_{\overline{\text{Im}(M)}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\overline{\text{Im}(M)}$.

Comment: @Schüler:  I think I understand.  I have edited my answer to correct a mistake, and to directly address your question, I hope.

Comment: @Schüler: Ah, I think I see.  The hint is actually at the very bottom of page 4 of the paper you link to.  I have yet again altered by answer.

Comment: Yes, I think that is right.  If you want, extend to the closures on both sides.

Comment: Dear Professor, please now I read again the proof. I'm facing confusion in the end of your proof: ''Thus
$$ V:\big( F/\ker M, \ip{\cdot}{\cdot} \big) \rightarrow \big( \im M^{1/2}, (\cdot|\cdot)_0 \big) $$
is an isometry, as you want.  Notice that $V$ is not (in general) onto.  Finally, we can extend $V$ to the completion of $F/\ker M$, and then we will obtain a unitary transformation onto $\overline{\im M^{1/2}}$, completion with respect to $(\cdot|\cdot)_0$.'' Since $V$ is not onto how we get an unitary operator? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because $V$ is defined between _incomplete_ spaces.  The continuous extension to the completions can be surjective without the original being surjective.

Comment: But we want that it will be necessary surjective in order to obtain an unitary operator. The completion is unique. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No.  In the abstract, suppose I have two inner-product spaces $H_0, H_1$ which are _not complete_ and so not Hilbert spaces.  It is quite possible to have an isometric linear map $T:H_0\rightarrow H_1$ which is _not_ surjective (that is, $T(H_0)$ is a proper subspace of $H_1$) but that once we extend $T$ by continuity to a map $\overline{H_0} \rightarrow \overline{H_1}$ we do obtain a surjection (which is then unitary).  In my answer the image of $V$ is the image of $M$ which might be a proper subspace of the image of $M^{1/2}$

Comment: For an example, let $H$ be an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, let $H_1=H$ and let $H_0$ be any dense subspace, and let $T$ be the inclusion map.  Then $T$ is not onto, but the completion of $H_0$ is (isometrically isomorphic to) $H$, and the continuous extension of $T$ is the identity, which is unitary.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, with regard to the above comment, I imagine that the claim is that the spaces are isometric in a natural way and this is indeed the case. For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that $M$ is injective and is multiplication by the positive sequence $(\lambda_n)$ on $\ell^2$.  Then a simple calculation shows that both spaces consist of the weighted $\ell^2$-spaces of sequences $(\xi_n)$ for which $\sum \lambda_n \xi_n^2 <\infty$.  One can use the spectral theorem to reduce to this case, at least for operators with discrete spectrum.  The general case is much the same except that,rather than  sequences, one has to consider multiplication operators on $L^2$-spaces.

I should perhaps add that one can prove this directly by con sidering the map, $x \mapsto M^{(1/2)} (x)$, factoring over the quotient by its kernel, and extending it to the completions.  This dispenses with the recourse to the spectral theorem, but only apparently since it is there implicitly in the use of the square root. I think the above version is more transparent but that is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

For $T\in B(F)$, we have $\ker T=\ker T^*T$ and $\ker T=(\text{Im} T^*)^\perp$, so for a positive operator $M$ we obtain
$\ker M^{1/2}=\ker M$, whence 
$$F=\ker M\oplus\overline{\text{Im} M}=\ker M^{1/2}\oplus\overline{\text{Im} M^{1/2}}$$ 
If $P$ denote the projection on $\overline{\text{Im} M}=\overline{\text{Im} M^{1/2}}$,then 
$$\langle M^{1/2}x,M^{1/2}y\rangle=\langle M^{1/2}Px,M^{1/2}Py\rangle=\langle MPx,Py\rangle=\langle Px,Py\rangle_M$$
so $F/\ker M=\overline{\text{Im} M^{1/2}}$ and the product defined on $F/\ker M$ is just the one defined on $\overline{\text{Im} M^{1/2}}$.